# Is there significance to the use of flame (φλόξ, phlox) without fire (πῦρ, pyr) in Greek scripture, specifically Luke 16:29?

Tags: greek

The Greek word "phlox" (φλόξ), meaning "flame", appears seven times in the Greek scriptures:

- Luke 16:29 — "*… for I am in anguish* [or *tormented*, or *sorrowed*, or *distressed*] *in this **flame***".
- Acts 7:30 — "*… in a **flame** of **fire** in a bush*".
- 2 Thessalonians 1:8 — "*in **flaming** **fire** …*".
- Hebrews 1:7 — "*… a **flame** of **fire***".
- Revelation 1:14 — "*… as a **flame** of **fire***".
- Revelation 2:18 — "*… a **flame** of **fire***".
- Revelation 19:12 — "*… as a **flame** of **fire***".

and three times in the Septuagint:

- Exodus 3:2 — "*… in a **flame** of **fire** …*".
- Isaiah 29:6 — "*… the **flame** of devouring **fire**".
- Joel 1:19 — "*… the **fire** hath devoured the pastures of the wilderness, and the **flame** hath …*".

In every case but one, it appears along with "fire".

Is there any possible significance (e.g. a different meaning or connotation) for its use in Luke 16:29, which *doesn't* refer to "fire"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question that involves the difference between Greek and Hebrew expressions/idiom.

It is well said that the NT is almost all written in Hebrew with Greek words.  This aphorism expresses the style of language used in the NT - it constantly uses Hebrew idiom and expressions but written in Greek language.

"Flame of fire" is a quintessentially Hebraic:

- Job 18:5 - Indeed, the lamp of the wicked is extinguished; **the flame of his fire** does not glow.
- Ps 29:7 - The voice of the LORD strikes with **flames of fire**.
- Num 21:28 - For **fire** came out from Heshbon, **flame** from the city of Sihon.
- Joel 2:5 - like the noise of **a flame of fire** that devoureth the stubble, as a strong people set in battle array.
- Ex 3:2 - And the angel of the LORD appeared to him in a **flame of fire** out of the midst of a bush. He looked, and behold, the bush was burning, yet it was not consumed.
- Dan 7:9 - “As I looked, thrones were placed, and the Ancient of Days took his seat; his clothing was white as snow, and the hair of his head like pure wool; his throne was **fiery flames**; its wheels were burning fire.
- Isa 4:5 - Then the LORD will create over the whole site of Mount Zion and over her assemblies a cloud by day, and smoke and the shining of a **flaming fire** by night; for over all the glory there will be a canopy.
- Isa 66:15 - “For behold, the LORD will come in fire, and his chariots like the whirlwind, to render his anger in fury, and his rebuke with **flames of fire**.
- Isa 22:6 - you will be visited by the LORD of Hosts with thunder and earthquake and loud noise, with windstorm and tempest and consuming **flame of fire**.

... and so forth.  Thus, "flames of fire" is a Hebrew expression.

It is significant that the sole exception to the observed occurrence of φλόξ occurs in a Greek parable/myth in Luke 16:29.  That is, the parable of the rich man and Lazarus is based in Greek myth and thus does not use as much Hebrew idiom.

**APPENDIX - Another example - "Burn with fire" = completely destroy**

Hebraic expressions were often redundant to add emphasis.  Here is a number of places where "burn with fire" means to completely destroy.

- Ex 12:10 - And you shall not leave any of it over until morning, but whatever is left of it until morning, you shall **burn with fire**
- Ex 29:14 - But the flesh of the bull and its hide and its refuse, you shall **burn with fire** outside the camp; it is a sin offering
- Lev 8:32 - The remainder of the flesh and of the bread you shall **burn in the fire**
- Lev 13:57 - and if it appears again in the garment, whether in the warp or in the woof, or in any article of leather, it is an outbreak; the article with the mark shall be **burned in the fire**.
- Lev 16:27 - But the bull of the sin offering and the goat of the sin offering, whose blood was brought in to make atonement in the holy place, shall be taken outside the camp, and they shall **burn** their hides, their flesh, and their refuse **in the fire**.
- Deut 7:25 - The graven images of their gods you are to **burn with fire**; you shall not covet the silver or the gold that is on them, nor take it for yourselves, or you will be snared by it, for it is an abomination to the LORD your God.
- Josh 11:6 - Then the LORD said to Joshua, "Do not be afraid because of them, for tomorrow at this time I will deliver all of them slain before Israel; you shall hamstring their horses and **burn** their chariots with **fire**.
- Ps 46:9 - Then the LORD said to Joshua, "Do not be afraid because of them, for tomorrow at this time I will deliver all of them slain before Israel; you shall hamstring their horses and **burn** their chariots **with fire**.
- Jer 43:13 - He will also shatter the obelisks of Heliopolis, which is in the land of Egypt; and the temples of the gods of Egypt he will **burn with fire**.
- Eze 23:47 - The company will stone them with stones and cut them down with their swords; they will slay their sons and their daughters and **burn** their houses with **fire**.